# map(&:id) work but not pluck(:id)

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

In part of my code I need to grab users's id but `pluck` doesn't grab them. Only `map(&:id)` can do it. I was wondering why.

I've wrote a quick and dirty block of code to find what's happen

```
  def remove_users user_ids
    p users_to_remove.class
    users_to_remove = self.users.where(id: user_ids)
    if users_to_remove.present?
      self.users -= users_to_remove
      self.save

      p users_to_remove.class
      p users_to_remove
      Rails::logger.info "\n#{users_to_remove}\n"
      users_to_remove_map = users_to_remove.map(&:id)
      p users_to_remove_map
      Rails::logger.info "\nmap id: #{users_to_remove_map}\n"
      users_to_remove_pluck = users_to_remove.pluck(:id)
      p users_to_remove_pluck
      Rails::logger.info "\npluck id: #{users_to_remove_pluck}\n"
      #...
    end
    self.user_ids
  end
```

Who return in my test.log

```
#<User::ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation:0x007fb0f9c64da8>


map id: [144004]

   (0.3ms)  SELECT "users"."id" FROM "users" INNER JOIN "groups_users" ON "users"."id" = "groups_users"."user_id" WHERE "groups_users"."group_id" = $1 AND "users"."id" IN (144004, 144005)  [["group_id", 235819]]

pluck id: []
```

And in my test

```
User::ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation
User::ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation
#<ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation [#<User id: 144004, created_at: "2015-08-06 08:55:11", updated_at: "2015-08-06 08:55:11", email: "user_2@test.com", token: "rpf5fqf5bs1ofme6aq66fwtcz", reset_password_token: nil, sign_in_count: 0, current_sign_in_at: nil, last_sign_in_at: nil, current_sign_in_ip: nil, last_sign_in_ip: nil, disabled: false, first_name: "John_2", last_name: "Rivers_4", is_owner: false, organisation_id: 235826, encrypted_password: "$2a$04$8ev1j...f6ICL.ezS....", reset_password_sent_at: nil, default_language: nil, uid: nil, api_key: "rmhh...noyn">]>
[144004]
[]
```

The strange thing is. I have user with id. `map` can get them. `pluck` not.

I don't understand sql log also. How can I get `map id` result without any select in sql log? Caching ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
users_to_remove = self.users.where(id: user_ids)
```

Doesn't fire off SQL query immediately. It sends the request whenever you need some details of these users. And it caches the result in SQL cache (so when the same request goes to DB again, it intercepted by Rails and never reaches the database).

So when you call:

```
users_to_remove.map(&:id)
```

It uses that cached result. But when you use

```
users_to_remove.pluck(:id)
```

It re-fetches the result, because the actual SQL query differs. With `#map` it is `SELECT * FROM ...`, and with `#pluck` it's `SELECT id FROM...`. And when query reaches the database, IDs doesn't belong to 'self' any longer (you deleted them right before that), so they aren't returned.

Comment: Mmmh I like your answer. So I've save ids using pluck in a variable before removing users and then use it. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

`pluck` doesnt work on an array, it works on an `ActiveRecord::Relation`, it's goal is to avoid to make a full query to only get the ids.

Once you've retrieved all columns from db, you can just `map` what you need.

You create the array when you do `self.users -= users_to_remove`, or maybe even when you do `.present?`, since you should use `.exists?`

Comment: Thanks again Benjamin ! Will validate the answer in few minutes. Can't for the moment.

Comment: but in my case. users_to_remove is an ActiveRecord::Relation ?

Comment: I've added users_to_remove.class before and after. I always get User::ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation. Will change the present? to exist?. Thanks