# Show request cached in test logs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, rspec, activesupport

I was wondering if it is possible to see in test logs the requests cached.

I've try to add in my `config/environments/test.rb`

```
ActiveSupport::Cache::Store.logger = Rails.logger
```

Don't know how I can change the logger level for rspec info like [mention in this post](http://hawkins.io/2012/07/advanced_caching_revised/) : `config.log_level = :debug`

Maybe it was only for rails 3. It's currently not working in Rails 4. Don't see any logs with cached information when running test and `tail -f log/test.log`.

This question is related to [map(&:id) work but not pluck(:id)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31851349/mapid-work-but-not-pluckid/31851394#31851394)

Comment: `Rails.logger.level = Logger::DEBUG`.

Comment: with config.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
config.logger.level = Logger::DEBUG I get log when running the test. But don't see any cached ressource.

Comment: Try `ActiveSupport::Cache::Store.logger.level = Logger::DEBUG` in `test.rb`.

Comment: it seems `Logger` is not define. block in <top (required)>': undefined method `level=' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)